# ReactJS how to create a tab menu dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and I want to build a tab navigation menu. So far I've installed [React-tabs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs) but I'm not sure how to create my own menu tabs based on an array forexample. I hope someone can help me out.

Here is my code sofar:

```
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';

export default class TabMenu extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(...arguments);

    let tabs = [
       { 'id': 1, 'name': 'Tab 1', 'url': '/' },
       { 'id': 2, 'name': 'Tab 2', 'url': '/' },
       { 'id': 3, 'name': 'Tab 3', 'url': '/' },
       { 'id': 4, 'name': 'Tab 4', 'url': '/' }
    ];

}

handleSelect(index, last) {
  console.log('Selected tab: ' + index + ', Last tab: ' + last);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className='tabmenu'>

      <Tabs onSelect={this.handleSelect} selectedIndex={2}>
        <TabList>
          <Tab>Tab1</Tab>
          <Tab>Tab2</Tab>
          <Tab>Tab3</Tab>
        </TabList>

        <TabPanel>
          <p>blablahblah</p>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
          <p>content blabla</p>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
          <p>more content blahblah</p>
        </TabPanel>
      </Tabs>          
    </div>
  );
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascripts map to create tabs dynamically for each element in array. Here is the example considering tabs as an accessible array inside render method.

```
<TabList>
  { tabs.map(tab =>
    <Tab key={tab.id}>{tab.name}</Tab>,
  )}
</TabList>
```